# Run Time Error 9 - Script out of Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a macro that is supposed to separate and add new worksheets based off one worksheet with all the data in it.

It won't run and I'm not sure why.

My code keeps hitting a **Run Time Error '9': Script out of range**. I'm not sure if it has something to do with the first sub or the second sub.

**The error occurs on line 16:**

> Set wsMain = wbMain.Sheets("MAIN")

**First sub:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim wbMain                      As Workbook
Dim wsMain                      As Worksheet
Dim rngMain                     As Range
Dim RngCategoryOne              As Range
Dim RngCategoryTwo              As Range
Dim RngCategoryThree            As Range
Dim RngCategoryFour             As Range
Dim RngCategoryFive             As Range
Dim RngCategorySix               As Range
Dim rng                         As Range
Dim SheetNames                  As Variant
Dim str                         As Variant

Set wbMain = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsMain = wbMain.Sheets("MAIN")
Set rngMain = wsMain.Range("F2:F3000")

For Each rng In rngMain
Select Case rng
    Case "HO NMX_AMO", "HO NMX_EUR", "WTI NMX", "DIESEL OHR EIA_AMO"
        If RngCategoryOne Is Nothing Then
            Set RngCategoryOne = rng
        Else
            Set RngCategoryOne = Union(rng, RngCategoryOne)
        End If
    Case "WTI NMX_AMO"
        If RngCategoryTwo Is Nothing Then
            Set RngCategoryTwo = rng
        Else
            Set RngCategoryTwo = Union(rng, RngCategoryTwo)
        End If
    Case "NG HH NMX"
        If RngCategoryThree Is Nothing Then
            Set RngCategoryThree = rng
        Else
            Set RngCategoryThree = Union(rng, RngCategoryThree)
        End If
    Case "RBOB NMX_EUR", "RBOB NMX_AMO"
        If RngCategoryFour Is Nothing Then
            Set RngCategoryFour = rng
        Else
            Set RngCategoryFour = Union(rng, RngCategoryFour)
        End If
    Case "GO ICE_AMO"
        If RngCategoryFive Is Nothing Then
            Set RngCategoryFive = rng
        Else
            Set RngCategoryFive = Union(rng, RngCategoryFive)
        End If
    Case "C3 CONW INW OPIS_APO, C3 MBEL TET OPIS_APO"
        If RngCategorySix Is Nothing Then
            Set RngCategorySix = rng
        Else
            Set RngCategorySix = Union(rng, RngCategorySix)

SheetNames = Array("AT, LB, LC, AS", "AO", "LN", "RF, RA", "ULA2", "8K, BO")

For Each str In SheetNames
    Call AddNewWorksheet(wbMain, str)
Next str

 wbMain.Sheets("AT, LB, LC, AS").Range("A1:A" & RngCategoryOne.Count) = RngCategoryOne.Value
 wbMain.Sheets("AO").Range("A1:A" & RngCategoryTwo.Count) = RngCategoryTwo.Value
 wbMain.Sheets("LN").Range("A1:A" & RngCategoryThree.Count) = RngCategoryThree.Value
 wbMain.Sheets("RF, RA").Range("A1:A" & RngCategoryFour.Count) = RngCategoryFour.Value
 wbMain.Sheets("ULA2").Range("A1:A" & RngCategoryFive.Count) = RngCategoryFive.Value
 wbMain.Sheets("8K, BO").Range("A1:A" & RngCategorySix.Count) = RngCategorySix.Value

  wsMain.Activate
  wsMain.Range("A1").Select
 End If
 End Select
Next
End Sub
```

**Second Sub:**

```
Sub AddNewWorksheet(ByRef wb As Workbook, ByVal wsName As Variant)
 With wb.Sheets
    .Add(after:=wb.Sheets(.Count)).Name = wsName
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: please format your code better. this at the bottom is painful to read:

End If
End Select
Next
End Sub

Comment: It might be useful to know what code line the error 9 occurs on.

Comment: @Jeeped It occurs on Line 16    Set wsMain = wbMain.Sheets("MAIN")

Comment: Do you have a sheet called MAIN?

Comment: Yes, Even when I run it, nothing happens! Im trying to extract the data that is in the F column, so for the ranges would i change it form A1:A to F?

Comment: I would say `sheets("Main")` does not exist and the code cannot find it. There is no other explanation. It has to be spelled in the code exactly. Check the sheet name and make sure all caps are the same and that there are no spaces in the sheet name.

Comment: Check for lagging spaces in your sheet name. Also, is there multiple books involved here? Or is the code housed in the book you are working on? If so, use **ThisWorkBook** instead of **ActiveWorkBook**. Your code could be looking for the sheet in the wrong book